# IIS 6 running constantly at around 40-50%

Tags: iis, iis-6

We recently installed a new version of an inhouse web application and according to the task manager the IIS process (w3wp.exe) is constantly using around 40-60% cpu while in previous version it was around 10%.  The web is running on IIS 6 and 2003 Windows Server.

Any ideas on what might be causing it?

Comment: The developers can't write code? The server was built in the Dark Ages? My guess is that it's partly both.

Comment: Also, Windows 2003?  Time to get with the current decade.

Comment: `according to the task manager the IIS process (w3wp.exe) is constantly using around 40-60% cpu` - Great. That means you've got 60-40% CPU available for other processes. Good work. "Oh no, my process/service/application is using the CPU". Yes. That's what they do.

Comment: Three smart-asses... just want the OP needs. If 2003 ain't broke, like millions of others in 2010 don't upgrade and break stuff... only a n00b would upgrade for the hell of it.

Comment: @Dawesi Funny and probably true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit turned out to be the .net Garbage collector.  Running the **% spent in** GC Performance Counter was revealing.

If the code is formatting strings with StringBuilder's **AppendFormat** take care as the GC struggles with cleaning up after it.  Modify the code to use a sequence of **Append** instead.